# Java убрать фон изображения

Tags: java, изображения

Здравствуйте! Дописал игру на Java, с использованием изображений. Но есть проблема. Изображения находятся в JFrame(BufferedImage 100x100 пикселей). Фон убрал в фотошопе,но в игре он снова появляется. Как это убрать? Изображения отрисовываются на JPanel, которой я и задаю размер 100 на 100. Пример изображения ниже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
public class Stand extends JPanel { // Подставка
    private StandDirection direction;

    private BufferedImage image;

    private int standX = 250;
    private int standY = 350;

    public int getStandX() {
        return standX;
    }

    public void setStandX(int standX) {
        this.standX = standX;
    }

    public int getStandY() {
        return standY;
    }

    public void setStandY(int standY) {
        this.standY = standY;
    }

    public Stand(){
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File("src\\images\\stand.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Неверный путь к изображению.");
        }
    }

    public void setDirection(StandDirection direction) {
        this.direction = direction;
    }

    public StandDirection getDirection() {
        return direction;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Может вы альфа-канал не используете? Покажите код.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, не использую,а что это? Код ниже.

Comment: @mrKott цвет может кодироваться 4 или 3 значениями, четверное значение - альфа канал. Оно обозначает прозрачность пикселя. Если его не использовать, все пиксели становятся непрозрачными.

Comment: @Maxgmer, и как его использовать? Можно код?

Comment: @mrKott я, к сожалению, с графикой на джаве не работал, но, погуглив, нашел метод setOpaque(false), который может помочь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я немного поэксперементировал с вашим изображением и близким к вашему кодом:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.LinearGradientPaint;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

class TestPane extends JPanel {
    private BufferedImage img;

    public TestPane() {
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("stand.png"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return img == null ? new Dimension(200, 200) : new Dimension(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        LinearGradientPaint lgp = new LinearGradientPaint(
                new Point(0, 0),
                new Point(0, getHeight()),
                new float[] {0f, 1f},
                new Color[] {Color.GREEN, Color.YELLOW});
        g2d.setPaint(lgp);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        if (img != null) {
            int x = (getWidth() - img.getWidth()) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight() - img.getHeight()) / 2;
            g2d.drawImage(img, x, y, this);
        }
        g2d.dispose();
    }
}

public class TestTransparency {
    public TestTransparency() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {}

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Тест");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(new TestPane());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestTransparency();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Проблем не обнаружил.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так как  я рисую на панели,а панелей у меня несколько, я панели задаю размер 100x100 методом setBounds(), вот что получается http://vfl.ru/fotos/4ce74c2217786569.html.

Comment: Так у вас фон не изображения, а панели. Правильным решением было бы рисовать изображения на графическом холсте напрямую, без участия панелей. Но можно обойтись и костыликом - в конструкторе ваших панелей вызывайте `setOpaque(false)`.

Comment: Разобрался,спасибо!